# Is there a way to create an Android desktop widget of PWA(progressive Web application)?

Tags: android, android-widget, progressive-web-apps

I'm building a progressive Web application.

Is there a way to create an Android desktop widget?

Comment: Do you want an icon on your desktop for your PWA? Android widget needs an Android app.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: There's a feature request for this in the Chromium issue tracker. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1170639