# Do PWAs support widgets

Tags: widget, progressive-web-apps

I have some temperature and flow rate readings being sent over to firebase from an ESP8266. In my existing website I can view those readings but I was wondering if I could make a PWA and then create a widget on my home screen (Android device) with those readings.

Is this currently feasible with a PWA or will I have to go native?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot create Android Widgets using a PWA today, you'll have to go with pure a Android implementation today. It's something we (the Chrome team) have considered, but haven't started working on.

Comment: What is the latest status on adding ability for PWA to include an "Android Widget"-like feature?

Comment: Found this issue in another SO question that has some more details on this status: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1170639 (source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65353617/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-android-desktop-widget-of-pwaprogressive-web-applic)

Comment: Any update on this functionality?

Answer (score 6):

One idea is to convert PWA to TWA ([Trusted Web Activity](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/)), which has support for homescreen widgets.

reference: https://firt.dev/pwa-playstore#advantages-over-standard-pwa-installation

Comment: Can you elaborate more? From what I understand, TWA is to open *your PWA* from *your Android app* - **which means a PWA and an android app are required.**

Answer (score 2):

Good news!

Microsoft has brought widget support to PWAs in their Edge Browser. For now it's only supported on Windows 11 and still experimental, but expect other Operating Systems to follow.

Read more about it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps-chromium/how-to/widgets

Comment: I was looking for share video from fileManger to facebook story . Is this under widget topic ? It was from android but I want to create in my PWA . For share I think we can use web share api . Is this share topic or widget ? Thanks

Comment: I think share_target is what I want . 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/share_target